# Unable to Access TypeScript Interface Attribute

Tags: typescript

I'm defining a cloud function in TypeScript via:

```
export async function updateDraftProject(data: {
    projectUpdates: {
        'submitted.about.categories'?: PrivateProjectInterface['submitted']['about']['categories'];
    };
}) => {
    ...
};
```

For the `data` object that should be passed as a parameter, I declare its structure, as containing a single property (with key `'submitted.about.categories'`) which is of type `PrivateProjectInterface['submitted']['about']['categories'];` (which should resolve to a `string`.

However, I get an error on this declaration, specifically on the `['about']` code, saying:

> Property 'about' does not exist on type 'ProjectContentInterface |
> undefined'.

I thought my interface is defined correctly, and am not sure why TypeScript thinks that `about` property does not exist on it.

**Interface Typescript File** (Relevant extract)

```
export declare interface PrivateProjectInterface {
    submitted?: ProjectContentInterface;
}

declare interface ProjectContentInterface {
    about?: {
        categories?: string[];
    };
}
```

Why does TypeScript not recognise the presence of `about` attribute?

Answer (score -1):

I think to fix this error you have two options. **Type assertion** or **type guarding**.

Overall the error appears because the `submitted` property of the `PrivateProjectInterface` is declared as a optional property of type `ProjectContentInterface | undefined`. By accessing the `submitted.about` property, it doesn't know whether the submitted property exists and is of type `ProjectContentInterface`, or if it doesn't exist and is `undefined`.

1. Type assertion: Tell TypeScript that the `submitted` property definitely exists and is of type `ProjectContentInterface`:

```
export async function updateDraftProject(data: {
    projectUpdates: {
        'submitted.about.categories'?: PrivateProjectInterface['submitted']['about']['categories'];
    };
}) => {
    const categories = data.projectUpdates['submitted.about.categories'];
    const about = (data.projectUpdates['submitted'] as ProjectContentInterface).about;
    ...
};
```

2. Type guard: Check that the `submitted` property exists before accessing the `about` property:

```
export async function updateDraftProject(data: {
    projectUpdates: {
        'submitted.about.categories'?: PrivateProjectInterface['submitted']['about']['categories'];
    };
}) => {
    const categories = data.projectUpdates['submitted.about.categories'];

    if (data.projectUpdates['submitted'] !== undefined && typeof data.projectUpdates['submitted'] === 'object') {
        const about = data.projectUpdates['submitted'].about;
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix the issue. I don't have problem when accessing the data, in fact, I can't quite event get to that point. My issue arises already when I declare the type of the `data` object which is passed as in input parameter. Hence, I get the error even if I have no code inside the function itself.

Comment: Yes, but as described, your typing says that it could be undefined and in the function you want to access it as it were defined, that's not possible. Because `ProjectContentInterface ` is not for sure in `PrivateProjectInterface `.

Comment: I see, I didn't realise it's not possible. Can you update your answer please to make it more explicit?